# Why won't my Samsung Galaxy Ace let me update my apps?

Tags: updates, samsung-galaxy-ace

Why won't my Samsung Galaxy Ace let me install updates? It lets me download, but then when it gets to installing it says:

> could not be installed on USB or SD card

Comment: Are you talking about Play Store apps update?

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible that you have a previous version with support for 'move to SD card' installed on your SD card but the update removed that support.

Thus it fails because replacing the app on the SD card is not allowed any more.

Try to move the culprit to the phone storage in advance and retry.

Answer (score 0):

You should move that app back to your internal storage then try to update it. Google Play can't update the app if it's stored on the SD card.

Comment: Is that really true? I see no reason why it shouldn't work if you used the official way to move the app to the SD card.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have enough space left on your SD card? To check free space, tap Settings > Storage > SD Card. You can also use the [Disk Usage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage&hl=en) app, which is my favorite third-party way of analyzing storage space on Android.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend removing and reinstalling the app to internal storage. Sometimes it's best to start off fresh.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem; apps2sd solved it!

Comment: Do you mean that apps2sd solved this same issue for you? Can you edit your answer to describe how?

Comment: How did apps2sd solve your problem? I can't seem to relate it to the question.